# How to convert Particular timezone of date into GMT timezone using esql of MQ?

Tags: gmt, ibm-integration-bus, extended-sql

I have the date of particular timezone, and I want to convert it to the GMT timezone, and then it needs to be inserted into DB using esql of MQ. Please help to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to convert a date from a format to another, you can do the following :

```
DECLARE inDate DATE;
DECLARE outDate DATE;
DECLARE tempDate DATE;
DECLARE patternIN CHARACTER 'yyyy-MM-dd';
DECLARE patternOUT CHARACTER 'yyMMdd';
SET tempDate = CAST(inDate AS DATE FORMAT patternIN);
-- Convert input String as Date (should match patternIN)
SET outDate = CAST(tempDate AS CHARACTER FORMAT patternOUT)
-- Convert the date object to the desired date format
```

Of course you need to be able to define your date pattern. I know you might need to separate the DATE from the TIME, but the object are exactly the same. A quick example of a specific cast :

```
CAST(CURRENT_DATE AS CHARACTER FORMAT 'yyyy-MM-dd') || 'T' || CAST(CURRENT_TIME AS CHARACTER FORMAT 'HH:mm:SS')
```

This will generate a date in the XML format, e.g : 2019-08-28T16:46:32

Comment: above ans is not related to my question.